# How to determine if the correct arguments were passed in getopts?

Tags: bash, getopts

I have a bash script that contains the following:

```
while getopts ":a:1:2:3:4" arg; do

case "$arg" in

a)
    a=$OPTARG
    ;;
1)
    one=$OPTARG
    ;;
2)
    two=$OPTARG
    ;;
3)
    three=$OPTARG
    ;;
4)
    four=$OPTARG
    ;;
```

There are two options for the argument `a` and suppose that they are the strings `"string1"` or `"string2"`. If `a` is given to be `"string1"` then arguments `1` and `2` must be provided. Similarly, if `a` is given to be `"string2"` then arguments `3` and `4` must be provided.

I need a way to verify that the user has specified the necessary parameters before continuing. So, in pseudo code it would be something like

```
if [ a == "string1" ]; then 

  if [1 and 2 were not given]; then

      echo "Arguments 1 and 2 were not given"
      exit

  fi

elif [ a == "string2" ]; then 

  if [3 and 4 were not given]; then 

      echo "Arguments 3 and 4 were not given"
      exit

  fi


fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getopts` doesn't support such validation, so you need to perform these checks explicitly, using a `case` statement:

```
case "$a" in
  string1)
    [[ -n $one && -n $two ]] || { echo "Arguments 1 and 2 were not given" >&2; exit 2; }
    ;;
  string2)
    [[ -n $three && -n $four ]] || { echo "Arguments 3 and 4 were not given" >&2; exit 2; }
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Unsupported -a argument: $a" >&2
    exit 2
esac
```

Comment: What does -n do with the variables?

Comment: I found it, -n x evaluates to true if x is not null.